# Remove HTML element in string MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the feeling I am almost there. I need to replace a HTML element within a string in MYSQL. I have searched other questions, but could not quite find the answer.

I already selected the string with the below query.

```
SELECT 
ID, 
post_title, 
substr(post_excerpt, instr(post_excerpt,'<img'), LOCATE('" />',post_excerpt,instr(post_excerpt,'<img')+30)-instr(post_excerpt,'<img') +4) as temp 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_excerpt LIKE '%<img%'
```

This gives me a table where I have the post_excerpt and the substring I need to remove from the post_excerpt, like this (the content of each row differs, but the output is as desired):

**Original HTML example**

```
<p><img style="margin-right: 10px; float: left;" src="images/stories/ifhhro/news/legal.jpg" alt="legal" width="73" height="55" />In a recent report published by the World Health Organization, the autors highlight the vital role of law reform in advancing the right to health.&nbsp;What are the most effective tools for doing this? This report&nbsp;illustrates how countries have enacted and implemented a wide range of laws and regulations with a demonstrable impact on the health and safety of their populations.</p>
```

**Needed HTML element to be removed example**

```
<img style="margin-right: 10px; float: left;" src="images/stories/ifhhro/news/legal.jpg" alt="legal" width="73" height="55" />
```

Any suggestions on how to complete this query so that it removes the element from the string?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason with this needs to be done with MYSQL specifically? You usually don't want to use it for that, when there are a great deal of programming languages that would take care of this before querying it over to MYSQL.

Comment: I only need to do this once for a large table (it is a migration of one website to another) and I thought this would be the fastest. It is not a repetitive task.